# Encrypting user data in transit for User Messaging Platform SDK for Android

Tags: android, encryption, ump

Does User Messaging Platform SDK for Android encrypts user data in transit ?
Data safety form in Play Console asks if all of the user data collected by your(my) app encrypted in transit.

Information here does not explain how user data were transfered:
https://developers.google.com/admob/ump/android/quick-start

Answer (score 1):

all data is encrypted as described in the Google privacy agreement.

"It uses encryption to keep your data private when it is moved"

https://policies.google.com/privacy

Admob, Firebase, Adsense, AdWords (Ads) and all services.

If this information is not correct, please write the correct source in response immediately. I filled out the Google Play Data security form as encrypted during data migration.

Answer (score 0):

On Apr 25, 2022 [the question was answered on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/AE8Gr-Pn0ss/m/AWwWd6mOAAAJ):

> [...]
>
> The UMP SDK writes the consent status into IAB defined TC string into
> SharedPreference on Android devices, which is not encrypted, so that
> any IAB conformed Ad networks' SDK can read it. The Google Mobile SDK
> encrypts the TC string when it reads it and sends the encrypted data
> to our server.
>
> Best,
> Jill
> Google Mobile Ads SDK Team
>
> [...]